# Some problems in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The problem is that I have created a dynamic navigation...
You click on a a-tag which has a function that displays some buttons.
I have assigned the function to the a-tag with an `addEventListener`.

It works in all the browsers, but IE...

When I click the  tag, buttons are not becoming visible. And no error appears.

P.S.: I'm spanish btw, I'm sorry about my english :3

/* Javascript */

```
window.onload = function() {
    var boton_menu = document.getElementById("boton_menu");

    /* Compatibilidad con navegadores web */
    if(boton_menu.addEventListener){
        boton_menu.addEventListener("click", menu_usuario, false);
    } else {
        if(boton_menu.attachEvent){
            boton_menu.attachEvent("onclick", menu_usuario);
        }
    }
}

/* Despliega el menú del usuario*/
function menu_usuario() {
    var boton_menu = document.getElementById("boton_menu");
    var perfil = document.getElementById("perfil");
    var ajustes = document.getElementById("ajustes");
    var desconectar = document.getElementById("desconectar");

    if(boton_menu.className == ""){
        boton_menu.className = "active";
        perfil.className = "active";
        ajustes.className = "active";
        desconectar.className = "active";
    } else {
        boton_menu.className = "";
        perfil.className = "";
        ajustes.className = "";
        desconectar.className = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery methods, like `.show()` to handle this effect? It is optimized to run in all current browsers.

Comment: Your code should work in IE11 as it is. Have you a proper DTD at the beginning of the file? Though the `attachEvent` alternative should take care of that too.

Comment: The problem isn't if it's optimized... It's that when I click on the a tag, it happens nothing...

Comment: What @bodruk means by 'optimized" is that it handles any differences in the browsers. That said; I don't see anything wrong with the code you have here. Can you produce some simple HTML that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Maybe it's a encoding error? I've had problems with accents (diacritics) on code in IE before...

Comment: ... or it could be a file encoding issue? The page uses UTF-8, but the file is not saved using UTF-8? Another element covers the link? Have you checked that IE has loaded the script, some relative paths are directed differently in IE. Is JavaScript allowed in Internet Options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Antonio Bueno">
        <title>Button Problems</title>
        <style>
            a {background-color: red; color: #FFF; padding: 10px;}
            a.active {background-color: blue;}
        </style>

        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var some_button = document.getElementById("some_button");

                if(some_button.addEventListener){
                    some_button.addEventListener("click", DisplayButton, false);
                } else {
                    if(some_button.attachEvent){
                        some_button.attachEvent("onclick", DisplayButton);
                    }
                }
            }

            function DisplayButton(){
                var some_button = document.getElementById("some_button");
                var another_button = document.getElementById("another_button");

                if(some_button.className == ""){
                    some_button.className = "active";
                    another_button.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    some_button.className = "";
                    another_button.style.display = "inline-block";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="some_button" class="">Click on me</a>
        <input id="another_button" type="submit" value="example" />
    </body>
</html>
```